# MobileFirst Android App giving alert "gap_init:2" on previewing

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-studio

I am trying to upgrade to MF 7.1 from MF 7.0. After upgrade, when I deployed the application on server and preview the Android App, it displays below alert message:

### [image]

I have following below steps to upgrade the project:

1. I used new eclipse for project upgrade: eclipse-jee-kepler-SR1-win32-x86_64.
2. Installed RTC 4.0.2 Client into the eclipse and restarted it.
3. Change the Workspace Text File Encoding to UTF-8.
4. Imported the MobileFirst 7.0 project from RTC.
5. Deleted "wlBuildResources" and "wlPreview" folders from %temp% ditecroty.
6. Installed MobileFirst Stidio IF : 7.1.0.0-MFPF-StudioP2-IF201509132345.
7. Restarted the eclipse.
8. Project upgraded to MF 7.1 successfully.
9. Installed the ADT To Eclipse using the update site and restarted the eclipse.
10. Right clicked on project name and Ran on MobileFirst Development Server.
11. Open the console and previewed the Android application and it displays the following alert: gap_init:2.

I have deleted , regenerated project but everytime I am getting this error. I have create a new project also
but I am getting the same alert message on previewing the Android application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens due to a regression and is taken care of in *APAR PI50036 CORDOVA "GAP_INIT:2" ERROR WHEN PREVIEWING ANDROID IN MBS*

To receive the fix once it is available you should open an IBM PMR (support ticket) and mention the APAR number above.

Comment: I opened the PMR: 39594 442 000. Will accept the answer if that solves the issue.

Comment: @IdanAdar..can you tell me when it can be available?

Comment: Hopefully early next week.